# Propel delete returns null

Tags: php, oop, orm, propel

What could be the reason behind `propel` returning `null` on `delete`? The following snippet

```
$m = new Users();
$m->save();
$key = $m->getId(); //get the last insert id

$q = new UsersQuery();
var_dump($q->findPk($key)->delete()); //yields NULL instead of int
```

Comment: have you made sure $key is returning an int value ? and are you sure UsersQuery is a valid entity ?

Comment: @YehiaAwad yes, it is returning a value and the entity is valid.

Comment: what is the difference between UsersQuery and Users entity ? are you sure a row with a PK $key exists in it ?

Comment: @YehiaAwad yes, it does exist! I am creating the row beforehand and using it's primary key (`id` is the only primary key, no composite keys).

Comment: I'm assuming you've verified that Propel is deleting the `Users` object?

Comment: I have same problem using "propel/propel": "~2.0@dev"

Answer (score 0):

In Propel v1.x delete returns a null, and in Propel v2.x returns the number of affected rows if supported by underlying database driver.